# Find child with biggest product value + java stream

Tags: java, stream

I have two classes. Child and Product with association many to many. Id like to find child who has the most products (product as a method parameter) using java stream :)

Thanks

Comment: Does the `Child` class have a list of `Product`s? You need to include a bit of code so we can make sense of what you're asking

Comment: Yes, Child has list of Products, Product has only a name field :)

Answer (score -1):

You need something like:

```
private Optional<Child> childWithMostProduct(String productName) {
    return childList.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingLong(ch -> ch.getProducts()
            .stream()
            .filter(pr -> pr.getName().equals(productName)).count());
}
```

Or if you have defined `equals` for Product:

```
private Optional<Child> childWithMostProduct(Product product) {
    return childList.stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(ch -> Collections.frequency(ch.getProducts(), product));
}
```

Here is a complete working example of the second model:

```
public record Child(String name, List<Product> productList) {
    private record Product(String name) { }

    public static Optional<Child> childWithMostProduct(List<Child> childList, Product product) {
        return childList.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(ch -> Collections.frequency(ch.productList, product)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product p1 = new Product("p1");
        Product p2 = new Product("p2");
        List<Child> childList = List.of(
                new Child("ch1", List.of(p1, p1, p2)),
                new Child("ch2", List.of(p1, p2, p2)));
        System.out.println(childWithMostProduct(childList, p1));
        System.out.println(childWithMostProduct(childList, p2));
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

> Optional[Child[name=ch1, productList=[Product[name=p1],
> Product[name=p1], Product[name=p2]]]]

> Optional[Child[name=ch2,
> productList=[Product[name=p1], Product[name=p2], Product[name=p2]]]]

Which is correct.

Comment: yeah, but this is only for all prodcut list, my child can have for example 5 products, p1,p2,p3,p4,p4. Other have p1,p1,p1,p2,p3,p4. And i want to create method which find me child with most product for exammple p4 is child1, for parameter p1 is child 2 :)

Comment: Ok that wasn't clear from your question. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @Lucas8912 both work perfectly. I have no idea what you are doing wrong. I'll add a complete working example to my answer.